# Leave at most max_dup consecutive duplicate elements in a list

Tags: python

I need to remove excessive duplicates of a particular element from the list, that is, if there's more than `max_dup` duplicates of selected elements in a slice of the list, leave at most `max_dup` elements in place. Obviously, stability (retaining order of elements in the list) is a must.

Example:

```
>>> remove_excessive_duplicates([1, '', '', '', 2, '', 3, '', '', '', '', '', 4, ''])
[1, '', '', 2, '', 3, '', '', 4, '']
```

The code I wrote:

```
def remove_excessive_duplicates(lst, dup='', max_dup=2):
    new_lst = []
    dcnt = 0
    for elem in lst:
        if elem == dup:
            dcnt += 1 
        else:
            dcnt = 0
        if dcnt > max_dup:
            continue
        new_lst.append(elem)
    return new_lst
```

It works, but I'm wondering if there's some cleverer way to do it, or the one that uses logic of some Python builtins to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a one-liner using the features of the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module. I'll try to show how you might find this via a step-by-step transformation.

1. When a function returns a list of items, it's often more convenient (in Python) to refactor it so that it *generates* the items one at a time using the `yield` statement. This has some advantages: (i) if the caller is also processing the items one at a time, then you don't need to allocate the whole list in memory; (ii) the first item becomes available immediately, without having to wait for all the items; (iii) if the items are arriving from a file or some other form of I/O, you may be able to process early items in parallel with loading later ones; (iv) a generator can operate on a potentially infinite stream of items without running out of memory.

   ```
   def remove_excessive_duplicates(iterable, dup='', max_dup=2):
       """Generate items in iterable, but at most max_dup of any consecutive
       sequence of items equal to dup.

       >>> input = [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]
       >>> list(remove_excessive_duplicates(input, dup=0))
       [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0]

       """
       count = 0
       for item in iterable:
           if item == dup:
               count += 1 
           else:
               count = 0
           if count <= max_dup:
               yield item
   ```

   (I've also taken the opportunity of adding a docstring and a [doctest](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html), and improving some of the variable names.)
2. What's going on here is that we are finding groups of identical items in the input, and for this Python provides [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

   ```
   for key, group in groupby(iterable):
       if key == dup:
           count = 0
           for item in group:
               if count >= max_dup:
                   break
               yield item
               count += 1
       else:
           yield from group
   ```

   This has the advantage that we don't need to maintain the running count in the `else` case, saving some work.
3. In the `if` case, we want to yield at most `max_dup` items from the iterable `group`. This can be done using [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

   ```
   for key, group in groupby(iterable):
       if key == dup:
           yield from islice(group, max_dup)
       else:
           yield from group
   ```
4. We can factor out the repeated `yield from`:

   ```
   for key, group in groupby(iterable):
       yield from islice(group, max_dup) if key == dup else group
   ```
5. That would a sensible place to stop. But to make this into a single expression we can note that the effect of this code is that for each group in the iterable, we construct an output iterable (either `islice(...)` or `group`, depending on the key), and the result consists of the concatenation of these iterables. Concatenating a bunch of iterables is a job for the obscurely named [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

   ```
   return chain.from_iterable(islice(group, max_dup) if key == dup else group
                              for key, group in groupby(iterable))
   ```